# How to accept value from user and change particular value in XML file and launch browser?

Tags: xml, batch-file, xml-parsing

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set freePort=
set newPort=

REM Checking the default value in XML file located at the path
FOR /F tokens^=4^ delims^=^" %%A in (
'type %~dp0\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\server.xml ^| find "httpEndpoint host="'
) do (
     echo: Default Port in XML = %%A
     set /a startPort=%%A

)
echo myCurrent port %startPort%

:SEARCHPORT
netstat -o -n -a | find "LISTENING" | find ":%startPort% " > NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" equ "0" (
  echo "port unavailable %startPort%"

 REM Here I want to ask user to enter a port number rather than hard-coded value ???
  set /a startPort=9080
  echo myNew port %startPort%
  GOTO :SEARCHPORT

) ELSE (
  echo "port available %startPort%"
  set freePort=%startPort%
  GOTO :FOUNDPORT
)

:FOUNDPORT
echo free %freePort%

REM here I want to change the value of the httpPort in XML and save the xml file, and then launch the default browser with https:\\localhost:<freePort>MyApp ???


)
@pause
```

---

The server.xml content is:

```
<server description="new server">

<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
    <!-- <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature> -->
</featureManager>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint host="27" httpPort="5357" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

<!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>


<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
```

Comment: I would highly recommend you use a scripting language that can natively read and write XML files.  Powershell, Vbscript or Jscript would be a few options.  In order for a batch file to do it, it has to use brute force to do it.

Comment: Almost done. I just want to put a new value for httpPort="< > " in the xml file  from the batch script. Can anyone give a simple few lines code

Comment: Try to use Xidel, cmdline tool to parsing XML documents. http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing an XML file with Windows command interpreter is awful. `cmd.exe` is designed for executing commands and applications and not for parsing XML files and modifying them. It would be definitely much better to write an executable with C, C++ or C# for this task instead of doing that with a batch file.

However, here is a commented batch file for replacing current port number of attribute `httpPort` by a new port number assigned to environment variable `NewPort` in the XML file `server.xml` which must be stored in same directory as the batch file. Please read the comments as this code has still some limitations like number for attribute `httpsPort` must be different to number of `httpPort` as otherwise two numbers are replaced at the same time.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem First check if the file to modify exists in directory of batch file.
set "XmlFile=%~dp0server.xml"
if not exist "%XmlFile%" goto EndBatch

rem Define some environment variables which are needed later.
set "NewPort=47680"
set "LineNumber="
set "LineCount=0"
set "TmpFile=%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"

rem Search for the line containing attribute httpPort and get its
rem line number and the line itself loaded into environment variables.

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /N /C:httpPort= "%XmlFile%" 2^>nul') do (
    set "LineNumber=%%I"
    set "PortLine=%%J"
)

rem If no line with attribute httpPort found, exit this batch file.
if not defined LineNumber goto EndBatch

rem Determine current number of attribute httpPort independent on where
rem this attribute is specified in the XML line and replace this number
rem in the line with the new port number as defined before.

rem It is required for this type of number replace that the other port
rem number for httpsPort is not the same number as current number for
rem httpPort as in this case both numbers would be replaced by the new
rem number. The attribute name and the equal sign cannot be included in
rem the string substitution as used here.

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PortNumber=!PortLine:*httpPort=!"
for /F %%I in ("!PortNumber:~1!") do set "PortNumber=%%~I"
set "PortLine=!PortLine:"%PortNumber%"="%NewPort%"!"
endlocal & set "PortLine=%PortLine%"

rem Make sure the temporary file used next does not already exist.
del "%TmpFile%" 2>nul

rem Copy all lines from XML file to a temporary file including empty
rem lines with the exception of the line containing attribute httpPort
rem which is copied to temporary file with the modified port number.
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /N "^" "%XmlFile%" 2^>nul') do (
    set "XmlLine=%%J"
    set /A LineCount+=1
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if not !LineCount! == %LineNumber% (
        echo/!XmlLine!>>"%TmpFile%"
    ) else (
        echo/!PortLine!>>"%TmpFile%"
    )
    endlocal
)

rem Overwrite original file with temporary file automatically deleted on success.
move /Y "%TmpFile%" "%XmlFile%" >nul

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

Much better would be using for example [JREPL.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid for replacing the value in the XML file using a regular expression.

```
@echo off
if not exist "%~dp0server.xml" goto :EOF
set "NewPort=47681"

call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "(httpPort=[\x22']?)\d*([\x22']?)" "$1%NewPort%$2" /I /F "%~dp0server.xml" /O -
```

By using `jrepl.bat` it does not matter what is the current value of attribute `httpPort` which could be even an empty string. The case-insensitive regular expression replace as used here would even handle the attribute `httpPort` with value enclosed in single instead of double quotes or not enclosed at all in quotes although that would not be valid for an XML file.

`\x22` is the hexadecimal notation for `"` used here to avoid problems with Windows command interpreter because the search argument string itself is enclosed in double quotes.